# Highcharts columnrange tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Why all item from 1st row have same tooltip, based on 2nd point     http://jsfiddle.net/Ye3Ak/243/ ?

```
    tooltip:{
        formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +' - ' +this.series.name +' - ' +this.point.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %H:%M',this.point.low)+
                    ' - ' +Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e %H:%M',this.point.high)+'<br/>';
            }
    },
```

Comment: Because you have points for the same x-value. Data should be sorted ascending without duplicated points. If you want to create gantt chart, see [this discussion](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bug, because in 4.0.4 it worked properly. I reported it to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3899

Comment: I will always specify 3rd party library version
I will always specify 3rd party library version
I will always specify 3rd party library version
I will always specify 3rd party library version
I will always specify 3rd party library version
I will always specify 3rd party library version